# Was ist "Phrasengebimmel"?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe vor kurzem das Drama *Vor Sonnenaufgang* von Gerhard Hauptmann gelesen und bin auf das Wort "Phrasengebimmel" (S. 81, Z. 20) gestoßen. Der betreffende Auszug (S. 81, Z. 14 ff.) lautet wie folgt:

> LOTH. [...] ich sagte Dir ja schon, meine Arbeitskraft gehört zum größten Theil meiner Lebensaufgabe und wird ihr immer zum größten Theil gehören: sie ist also nicht mehr mein, ich hätte außerdem mit ganz besonderen Schwierigkeiten . . . . . .
>   
>   HOFFMANN. Pst! klingelt da nicht Jemand?
>   LOTH. Du hälst das für Phrasengebimmel?
>   HOFFMANN. Ehrlich gesagt, es klingt etwas hohl! [...]

Für mich klingt das Ganze sehr nach Sarkasmus seitens Hoffmanns. Das Klingeln ("Pst! klingelt da nicht Jemand?") steht für die von Hoffman empfundene Dummheit oder Sinnlosigkeit von Loths Äußerungen, also "[...] meine Arbeitskraft gehört zum größten Theil meiner Lebensaufgabe [...]". "Phrasengebimmel" ist also eine herablassende Bezeichnung für das Verwenden von "klugen Worten" und bezieht sich hier konkret auf die altruistische Ideologie Loths. Seine Lebensaufgabe ist nämlich, andere glücklich zu machen (vgl. S. 59, Z. 24 f.)

Stimmt das oder weiß da jemand genauer Bescheid? Google Ngram Viewer findet keinen Treffer und das Wort taucht auch nicht im Duden auf, weshalb ich nach einer genauen Bedeutung des Worts frage.

Comment: Für mich klingt deine Lesart rechtwohl angemessen. (Bimmel, bimmel)

Comment: Übrigens, das verwandte *Wortgeklingel* jedenfalls ist der Duden-Redaktion ausweislich ihres Internet-Auftritts geläufig. http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Wortgeklingel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Gebimmel* ist eine umgangssprachliche, negativ wertende Bezeichnung für *Aufsehen erregen*. Mit *Phrasen* sind hier leere Worthülsen gemeint. Als mit viel Reden sehr wenig inhaltlich beitragen. Das Wort ist eine kreative Wortschöpfung des Autors, aber meiner Meinung nach leicht zu verstehen in diesem Dialogkontext. Ich glaube, es auch schon ab und zu so irgendwo gehört zu haben; jedenfalls erscheint es mir geläufig.